# Mulitvariable Calculus: Vectors of tangent plane

Tags: calculus

**Problem**
Let $M$ be the surface consisting of the points $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ for which $x^2+y^3+z^4=1$. Which vectors $v\in \mathbb{R}^3$ belong to the tangent plane to M at the point $(x,y,z)=(1,-1,1)$?

**Attempt**
So I got the gradient to be $\nabla=2x+3y^2+4z^3$. I then subbed in the point:

$$\nabla(1,-1,1)=(2,3,4)$$

The tangent plane was then gotten by:

$$2(x-1)+3(y+1)+4(z-1)=0$$ 
$$2x+3y+4z=3$$

I think there is more to do here but I'm unsure what. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That's the right answer.  For what it's worth, the gradient is a vector field, i.e. $\nabla f(x,y,z) = (2x,3y^{2},4z^{3})$.  You seemed to get this in your first in-line equation, but not when you gave your formula for the gradient.  Alternatively, your first equation could have read: $\nabla f(x,y,z) = 2x \hat{i} + 3y^{2} \hat{j} + 4z^{3} \hat{k}$.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. Does leaving the answer as it is answer the question sufficiently though? Or do I just say $v_1=2x, v_2=3y, v_3=4z$?

Comment: If you are referring to the $\nu$, the appeared in the problem statement, this is not correct.  A vector in the tangent plane is \textbf{not} just $(2x, 3y, 4z)$.  Think about it: what are $x$, $y$, and $z$?  We are looking for vectors, not functions.  The tangent plane $M$ is $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \, \mid \, 2x + 3y + 4z = 1\}$.

Comment: Is there unit vectors that have to be found?